# Invalid or corrupt jarfile, Run javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, ubuntu-22.04

My application code

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    private static Scene scene;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        
        FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader(LoginControler.class.getResource("loging.fxml"));
        scene = new Scene(fxmlloader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
}
```

I was trying to run  above javafx application using terminal,But i get this error. Please tell me did i make a mistake in script. I have used *maven-shade-plugin* to build jar with dependencies

```
root@abc-abc2051A:~# java -jar --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules javafx.controls myjar-1.0.0-shaded.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib
```

Application Running Enviornment

- OS - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Architecture 64bit
- Java - OpenJDK 1.8.0_362

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage for `java` is:

```
% java --help
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)
```

I.e. the jar file should immediately follow the `-jar` option (whicbh should come after any other options). So you need

```
java --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -jar myjar-1.0.0-shaded.jar
```

Comment: But in window it work perfectly. only the javafx sdk path represent changes.

Comment: @Kanishka I don't have a windows machine to test with, but `java` (i.e. the Java runtime) is a native application. There is no a priori reason for it to have the same syntax on every system. The bottom line here is that that the specification says `-jar <jarfile>` comes after the JVM options, so you need to call it that way.

Comment: I tried what java specifications says. but it gives a new error```Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: If `--module-path` is not a recognized option, then you have an old (outdated) version of `java`. What does `java --version` give?

Comment: I use java 8 runtime environment Java - OpenJDK 1.8.0_362

Comment: @Kanishka You need a more up to date version. Modules were introduced in version 9 (which is why you get the error you get). The current version is version 20.

Comment: I typed java and as you said it's not telling anything about modules. I will check on it

Comment: @Kanishka of course Java 8 doesn't tell you anything about modules.  Java 8 was created before the module system, so there is no way it could know anything about modules.  JavaFX 11+ was designed only to work with modules.  Anyway, instructions on getting started with JavaFX are at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), remove all the old stuff from your system (e.g. Java 8 and JavaFX 11), and start again from scratch using a recent version of both (20+), following the getting started instructions exactly.  Anything else, and you risk spending a lot of time for no return.

Comment: What jewelsea said, plus: Search Stack Overflow to learn more. Starting with JavaFX/OpenJFX has been addressed several times, as has [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).

Comment: @Kanishka "_But in window it work perfectly. only the javafx sdk path represent changes_" – Anything after `-jar <jarfile>` becomes part of `[args...]`. In other words, it becomes part of the **application arguments** (the values of the string array passed to your main method). So, if you had `java -jar foo.jar --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib` then `--module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib` would not be interpreted as a JVM option but as two application arguments.

Comment: However, since you had `java -jar --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib foo.jar` (i.e., the module-path option between the `-jar` option and the JAR file), it apparently ignored `--module-path` and tried to use `/opt/javafx-sdk-11/lib` as the JAR file. But that's a directory, thus the error.

Comment: I have upgraded my Java runtime and checked. Application successfully started. Thanks for the support and thing tought me.Now I know thing I need to check when implimenting application in java enviornment.@James_D and others